# DATE_SUB with configurable value

Tags: mysql-5.7, aws, date-math

In MySQL you can use the DATE_SUB function to get a new date based on the values passed in. For example I can use the following to get the a date of 30 days ago from when I run the function

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY);
```

Is it possible to use that function or something similar to be able to pull in a value from another config table to determine how many days you want to go back?

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL x DAY);
```

This is part of a project to move records from live table to an archive table after a set number of days and I would like to be able to set that up as a configureable value.

This is being run as a daily event on a MySQL 5.7 instance that is setup in AWS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL (select interval from yourconfigtable) DAY);
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for but couldn't find the syntax.